# Embed Firefox in Java

Tags: java, linux, firefox, webview

I've looked everywhere but I couldn't find the right answer to what I'm looking for. What I'm trying to accomplish is embed Firefox into a Java application which will be running in Linux. The Java application is supposed to act like a web browser with a toolbar that contains the usual address bar and back and forward buttons.

I've so far tried Java WebView. That's the closest I've ever gotten to my goal, except that I have no clue how to include a simple text
bar within that same application that can take you to different sites (the address bar) and the usual back and forward buttons.

If anyone's willing to help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use an embedded browser

[jbrowser : Java browser based on mozilla embedded api.](https://github.com/caiiiycuk/jbrowser)